# CCavenue Could not able to get the return status of the transaction?

Tags: php, payment-gateway, ccavenue

I had integrated ccavenue in my website using the php scripts provided by the provider. i used a live card to test the transaction and its succeeded but not able to get the payment status. its not returning to the return url, its display status in the ccavenue site itself, please anyone help me on this to get the payment status information.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In the form the Redirect_Url field must be included with the fully qualified URL check it out.

```
<input type="hidden" name="Redirect_Url" value="www.mywebsite.com">
```

Comment: i have checked the return url and cannot find any issues, my website does not have an ssl connection, is this a problem in the redirection ?

Comment: No I think ssl will not be a problem. There might be some configuration issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to activate the working key from CCAvenue Panel in settings & options -> working key -> click on submit.

By default radio button is on Activate and you have to set on deactivate. See image below. It should look like this. If you don't have access ask your client to do this.

[image]